# Jenkins jobs are missing on Win 10

Tags: java, jenkins, jobs

I have a Jenkins installation on win 10. I always run it via console with command `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090` because of port number. And I have some jobs created in there. Today I decided to change settings in **jenkins.xml** for port so I can run it automatically as **Windows service**. When I started Jenkins as Win service in services window everything looks ok BUT all jobs are missing. If I stop the service and rerun Jenkins via console command all jobs are ok. I don'd understand. There is a folder **Users/xy/.jenkins/jobs** where I can see all the jobs created. So why the service dont see them? Another think I noticed around this problem is the service calls **jenkins.exe** and console calls **jenkins.war**. Does anybody knows what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you backup-ed everything first.

You have basically two installations pointing to different folders. You can define in both installations a job that outputs the environment (you need to know the jenkins home & workspace paths). After that you can copy (not move) the old folder content to the new one.

Comment: I dont understand this sentence - You can define in both installations a job that outputs the environment (you need to know the jenkins home & workspace paths) Why shoul I define a job in both instalations? Job is an instance under the Jenkins not above it. Can you explain it or give me a link?

Comment: I made myself misunderstood - sorry for that!  You don't have to make two installations. The service you created acts like a second, separate installation because it cannot read the profile files from your user ( ~/.jenkins) and creates a new set. Look for something like this in the config file: "<env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="D:\JenkinsHome"/>" . Take the data stored under your profile and copy it to the new location, then start the service. Do not use "move" as you still want to have the old location intact until you make the new one functional.

Comment: Also as a good practice set the workspace folder outside jenkins_home so you can backup all configurations and build definitions without the overload of the workspace. Always make a backup before installing & upgrading plugins as it is easy to break things there.

Comment: I copied the user .jenkins files and folders to root jenkins directory and it starts to show the jobs. But none of them are able to run. It fails ... I am going to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

When you run jenkins as a service did you specify it to run as your user account or as System?  Jenkins stores information in its user directory and usually services either run as System or in their own dedicated account

Comment: I dont know. I comes from installation file. Why it is not the same?